# Java File() как указать путь к подключаемому устройству

Tags: java

Написал простецкую утилиту, которая меняет имена файлов в директории. При выборе директории на харде все ок, но планировалось изначально использовать утилиту для файлов на плеере. Когда использую на плеере, ловлю `NullPointerException`, путь следующий: `Компьютер\WALKMAN\Storage Media\MUSIC\`
Куда копать?

Comment: Плеер хотя бы определяется как съемный диск в системе?

Comment: В Windows не бывает путей начинающихся с `Компьютер`.

Comment: Вот именно, как съемный диск просто не определяется. Он сразу отправляется в "устройства и принтеры". Да, я понимаю что таких путей не бывает, потому и пишу здесь)

Comment: А как вы этот путь вывели? Если войти в свойства любого файла в устройстве (через проводник) там будет именно такой путь?

Comment: Что вам вернет вот такой метод? `File.listRoots()`

Comment: Да, путь в топе и был взят из свойств файла на устройстве.

Answer (score 1):

Вот очень похожий вопрос с ответами, надеюсь, поможет Вам:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12841327
Используя JMTP библиотеку https://code.google.com/p/jmtp/

```
package jmtp;

import be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException;
import be.derycke.pieter.com.Guid;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import jmtp.PortableDevice;
import jmtp.*;

public class Jmtp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
        PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
        // Connect to my mp3-player
        device.open();

        System.out.println(device.getModel());

        System.out.println("---------------");

        // Iterate over deviceObjects
        for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
            // If the object is a storage object
            if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
                PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

                for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
//                    
//                        BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
//                        File file = new File("c:/JavaAppletSigningGuide.pdf");
//                        try {
//                            storage.addAudioObject(file, "jj", "jj", bigInteger1);
//                        } catch (Exception e) {
//                            //System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
//                        }
//                    

                    System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                }
            }
        }

        manager.getDevices()[0].close();

    }
}
```

Необходимо добавить файлы jmtp.dll (включены в файл загрузки jmtp) [как native библиотеки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans).

Comment: Хм... Я экспортировал проект на свой GitHub, но в проекте нет файла jmtp.dll

Comment: @Dmitresso
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/jmtp/jmtp_beta2.zip - здесь есть